# How to make a python file executable in windows

Tags: django, windows, python-2.7, dos

We used to make a python file executable by chmod +x manage.py. So we were able to execute like this ./manage.py. But i am using windows CLI and what command should i used to make that manage.py executable. I am not able to understand from the docs of python.org

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

1. Right Click on the a .py file and go to Properties.
2. Click "Change" on "Opens With" and browse for the location of your python executeable.

Suppose Python is installed in "D:\Program Files\Python\python.exe" then you need to key in

```
D:\Program Files\Python\python.exe "%1" %*
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try cx_Freeze? It freezes the document and makes it executable.

http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

I love using it; it allows people who don't have Python installed on their computers to run and execute the file.